Error while reading a file using pyspark against a spark container running on docker
I have a simple python script:
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import collections

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("RatingsHistogram")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

lines = sc.textFile("/opt/bitnami/spark/appdata/ml-100k/u.data")
ratings = lines.map(lambda x: x.split()[2])
result = ratings.countByValue()

sortedResults = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(result.items()))
for key, value in sortedResults.items():
    print("%s %i" % (key, value))

It's from a tutorial.  It reads data from a CSV file containing ratings for movies (3,4,5 stars, etc) and tells gives me a count of all the ratings.
The data is on my file system in a folder called "data".  So in my docker-compose file, I mounted the data folder to /opt/bitnami/spark/appdata
I'm using the following docker-compose.yml:
# Copyright VMware, Inc.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: APACHE-2.0

version: '2'

services:
  spark-master:
    image: bitnami/spark:latest
    volumes:
      - './data:/opt/bitnami/spark/appdata'
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_USER=spark
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '7077:7077'
  spark-worker:
    image: bitnami/spark:latest
    volumes:
      - './data:/opt/bitnami/spark/appdata'
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_USER=spark
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'

This starts a master node and a worker node.
When I run this from my host machine:
spark-submit --master spark://localhost:7077 ratings-counter.py
I get the following error:
24/04/14 00:11:30 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\development\spark-sandbox\ratings-counter.py", line 15, in <module>
    result = ratings.countByValue()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\development\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2662, in countByValue
  File "C:\development\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1924, in reduce
  File "C:\development\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1833, in collect
  File "C:\development\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "C:\development\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/opt/bitnami/spark/appdata/ml-100k/u.data
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:304)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:244)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:332)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:208)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:294)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:290)

I'm not clear on why this is happening.  From what I've read, the file need to be accessible from the worker node.  When I log into my worker node in docker, I do see the file there:
$ pwd
/opt/bitnami/spark/appdata/ml-100k
$ ls -altr u.data
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1979173 Apr 13 05:20 u.data

It seems to be looking for the file in the hosts (non-docker) filesystem...  because when I change the python script to read it from the hosts location - the job gets submitted fine, but the worker node throws errors that it cannot find the file..
What am I doing wrong or not understanding?
